# Debugger shows null value despite having value in Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to send a value through intent, but my app was getting crashed. So, I try to check the value in the debugger and it is showing null. Here is the image.

[image]

As you can see that it shows `userId = "null"` and `profilephotoURl ="null"`. **Why is this happening?**

And here is the image of the Database.

[image]

Here is the Code

**ProfileInfo.class**

```
public class ProfileInfo {

String userName, profilePhotoUrl, phoneNumber, userId;

public ProfileInfo() {}

public ProfileInfo(String userName, String profilePhotoUrl, String phoneNumber, String userId) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.profilePhotoUrl = profilePhotoUrl;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.userId = userId;
}

public ProfileInfo(String userName, String phoneNumber) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}


public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public String getProfilePhotoUrl() {
    return profilePhotoUrl;
}
```

**UserAdapter.class**

```
public class UsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ProfileInfo> minfo;
    public static final String USER_ID = "userid";
    Context context;

    public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ProfileInfo> minfo) {
        this.context = context;
        this.minfo = minfo;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_item, parent, false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ProfileInfo profileInfo = minfo.get(position);
        holder.username.setText(profileInfo.getUserName());
        holder.phoneNumber.setText(profileInfo.getPhoneNumber());
        holder.id.setText(profileInfo.getUserId());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MessageLayout.class);
                intent.putExtra(USER_ID, profileInfo.getUserId());
                Log.d("UserID:", profileInfo.getUserId());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return minfo.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView username;
        TextView phoneNumber, id;
        CircleImageView profileImage;
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user);
            phoneNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
            id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
            profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.circleProfileImage);
            relativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

        }
    }
}
```

**MessageLayout.class**

```
public class MessageLayout extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseUser currentUser;
    DatabaseReference db, chatDb;
    EditText message;
    ImageButton sendMessage;
    TextView username;
    CircleImageView profileImage;
    String recieverId, messageText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_layout);

        message = findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);
        sendMessage = findViewById(R.id.sendMessage);
        username = findViewById(R.id.displayUsername);
        profileImage = findViewById(R.id.circledp);
        currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        recieverId = intent.getStringExtra(UsersAdapter.USER_ID);

        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserInfo").child(recieverId);
        chatDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chats");
        db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ProfileInfo info = dataSnapshot.getValue(ProfileInfo.class);

                username.setText(info.getUserName());
                Glide.with(MessageLayout.this).load(info.getProfilePhotoUrl()).into(profileImage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: At which line of code are you getting those null values?

Comment: @AlexMamo In UserAdapter.class when i am trying to send the value through input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your constructor. It seems like your datasnapshot is being cast using your `ProfileInfo(String userName, String phoneNumber)` constructor.

Here's what you can do: Ensure that there are only two constructors in your model class: The regular no-argument constructor and then your full-blown constructor. Something like this:

```
public ProfileInfo() {}

public ProfileInfo(String userName, String profilePhotoUrl, String phoneNumber, String userId) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.profilePhotoUrl = profilePhotoUrl;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.userId = userId;
}
```

Then, run your code and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I wanna know what should I do if I have to use the constructor with Username and PhoneNumber? Should I pass other values as null?

Comment: Passing the other values as null is cool, but then, your app stands the risk of crashing if you perform any get() operation on any of the null variables. A better approach would be having default values for them when they are null. For instance, "NOT_SET_YET". I'm sure there should be a better approach than this but this is the best I can come up with for now... plus, it's guaranteed to work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will definitely try it.

Answer (score 0):

In you model class, there should be a single parameterized constructor.Try commenting the second parameterized constructor and see if that helps.